# How to set a component non-reactive data in Vue 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vuejs2

I have a categories array, which is loaded once (in created hook) and then it is static all the time. I render these array values in a component template.

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="item in myArray">{{ item }}</li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

My data property looks (it does not include myArray - I don't want reactive binding):

```
data() {
    return {
        someReactiveData: [1, 2, 3]
    };
}
```

My create hook:

```
created() {
    // ...
    this.myArray = ["value 1", "value 2"];
    // ...
}
```

Problem is, that Vue throws error - I can't use myArray in a template, because this variable is not created when the DOM is created - mounted.

So how to do this? Or where can be stored component constants?

Comment: Why not use session/local Storage?

Comment: More read on this topic is available in Vue issue https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1988

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Vue sets all the properties in the `data` option to setters/getters to make them reactive. See [Reactivity in depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

Since you want `myArray` to be static you can create it as a custom option which can be accessed using [`vm.$options`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options)

```
export default{
    data() {
        return{
            someReactiveData: [1, 2, 3]
        }
    },
    //custom option name myArray
    myArray: null,
    created() {
        //access the custom option using $options
        this.$options.myArray = ["value 1", "value 2"];
    }
}
```

you can iterate over this custom options in your template as follows:

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="item in $options.myArray">{{ item }}</li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0xddavh2/6/)

Comment: Not so nice because it puts non-reactive data into another namespace $options, instead of mixing these with reactive data, which would be more preferable to update at once.

Comment: @DmitriySintsov I don't understand, isn't that the whole goal?  A place to attach non-reactive data on the model?

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same with TypeScript?

Comment: The way you describe it in your solution, `myArray` will be shared across all instances of that component. Is there a way to have non-reactive data per instance?

Comment: @mediafreakch add a prop named `addNonReactive` and set it to be false by default. Use this prop `this.addNonReactive` in created hook to check whether add non reactive data or not. Pass true in component props if you want to add non reactive data.

Comment: solved it using the `beforeCreate` hook, where I just assign `this.myNonReactiveProp`. After that it is usable in templates, methods and other hooks.

Comment: This works but is not TS-friendly, unfortunately

Comment: @zero298 I'm late to the party, but I just stumbled upon a use case: storing large dynamic objects (like a Babylonjs scene) can be a problem since reactivity takes time, interrupting the rendering process. It's advised not to use in data.

Answer (score 37):

Actually, setting properties on `this` in `created()` should work out of the box:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in myArray" :key="item">
        {{ item }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "app",
  created() {
    this.myArray = [
      'item 1',
      'item 2'
    ];
  }
};
</script>
```

will render

```
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li>
      item 1
    </li>
    <li>
      item 2
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/r0yqj2orpn .

Comment: So if you add data with 'this' but it's not defined in the 'data' part of the component, it will be static data?

Comment: `static` already has a meaning in Javascript (and class-based languages in general), where it means a value that's shared by all instances of a class. That's not what's happening here. `myArray` will *non-reactive*, i.e. Vue won't proxy it and watch it for changes.

Answer (score 7):

> I prefer using static data (non reactive) like this:

**Create a mixin (i name it `static_data.js`) with the follow content**

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.prototype.$static = {}

export default {
  beforeCreate () {
    const vue_static = this.$options.static
    const vue_static_destination = this.$static || this

    if (vue_static && typeof(vue_static) === 'function') {
      Object.assign(vue_static_destination, vue_static.apply(this))
    } else if (vue_static && typeof(vue_static) === 'object') {
      Object.assign(vue_static_destination, vue_static)
    }      
  }
}
```

**In your components where you want to use static data you can do:**

```
import use_static_data from '@mixins/static_data'

export default {
  mixins: [use_static_data],

  static: () => ({
    static_value: 'Vue is awesome'
  }),

  created () {
    console.log(this.$static.static_value); // Vue is awesome
  }
}
```

There is also a package [vue-static](https://github.com/samuelantonioli/vue-static)

Credits [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1988).

Answer (score 6):

If you want to keep it in `data`, the proper way is using [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze), as described in the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods):

> The only exception to this being the use of Object.freeze(), which
> prevents existing properties from being changed, which also means the
> reactivity system can’t track changes.

Comment: if the code is `data() {  return { something: Object.freeze({1:2}) }  }`,
`this.something[1] = 3` will throw an error because the obj is freezed,
but `this.something = {2:3}` will still work. So this isn't a good way to create non-reactive data

Answer (score 1):

You can try this line of code. You can copy an object and remove the reactivity.

```
var newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <template>
  <div id="app">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in myArray" :key="item">
        {{ item }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "app",
  data () {
    this.myArray = [
      'item 1',
      'item 2'
    ];
    return {}
  }
};
</script>
```