# How to make a template variable non-reactive in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I have an edit form with variables held in the data(). I don't want the title of the edit page to update yet I want to maintain the v-model sync of data between the input and data. What's the simplest way to make the title non-reactive in the h1 tag? Mr You has to have something up his sleeve for this..

```vue
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <input v-model="title">
    </div>
</template>

<script>    
export default {
    data: {
        title: 'Initial value'      
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I wanted to see if there was another way, something like a v-static directive. The title referencing the same data variable. i.e. Editing {{ title }}

Comment: If you want one-way binding, use `:value="title"` instead of `v-model`

Comment: @RoyJ but this is only for inputs with attribute 'value'? What about outputting, as above into a heading tag for example.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a component non-reactive data in Vue 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814507/how-to-set-a-component-non-reactive-data-in-vue-2)

Answer (score 5):

The Vue [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods) recommend [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) on the returned object in `data()` to disable reactivity on properties:

```
data() {
  return Object.freeze({ title: 'Initial value' })
}
```

But the caveat is it freezes *all* properties (it doesn't look like there's a way to freeze only some properties using this method), and **using `v-model` with this causes console errors (`Cannot assign to read only property`)**.

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() { 
    return Object.freeze({
      message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <input v-model="message"> <!-- XXX: Cannot use v-model with frozen property. This will cause a console error. -->
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could arbitrarily remove the reactivity from any configurable data property by [redefining it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) with `writeable: false`:

```
methods: {
  removeReactivity() {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'title', {value: null, writeable: false});
  }
}
```

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() { 
    return {
      message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    removeReactivity() {
      Object.defineProperty(this, 'message', {value: null, writeable: false});
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <input v-model="message">

  <div>
    <button @click="removeReactivity">
      Remove reactivity for <code>message</code>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your first snippet generates errors because Vue tries to write to the frozen object.

Comment: Yep. That caveat stated in the description beforehand.

Answer (score 5):

You could potentially use `v-once` directive for your purpose if you don't want to create a separate variable for `input`. From the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-once):

> Render the element and component once only. On subsequent re-renders,
> the element/component and all its children will be treated as static
> content and skipped.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    title: "initial value"
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model="title">
  <p>Reactive title: {{ title }}</p>
  <p v-once>Static title: {{ title }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want the input to change the value of your data item, use `value` to bind it rather than the two-way `v-model`. Then it just acts as an initializer for the input.

If you want to have two values, one that doesn't change and one that does that gets initialized from the other, you need to have two data items. The non-changing one can be a [`prop` with a default value](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation). The other is a `data` member which, if you use a `data` function, can initialize itself to the prop value.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  props: {
    initTitle: {
      default: 'Initial value'
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      title: this.initTitle
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{ initTitle }}</h1>
  <input v-model="title">
  <div>Title is "{{title}}"</div>
</div>
```

You could alternatively use the little-known [`$options`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options) properties to define your title as a sort of internal constant rather than a prop. I am of mixed feelings about whether this is a good design approach or a step too weird.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  initTitle: 'Initial value',
  data() {
    return {
      title: this.$options.initTitle
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{ $options.initTitle }}</h1>
  <input v-model="title">
  <div>Title is "{{title}}"</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also considered and weirded out by using $options for such a thing. Ended up defining a separate data variable on init.

Answer (score 0):

*Working backwards from [the contents of this blog](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/03/05/vue-js-reactivity/)...*

It appears that when you create an object for Vue, it creates the properties with reactive getters and setters. If you then append a property to that object out-of-band, then it won't get the reactive capability, but will still be accessible as a value.

This should solve it for you:

```vue
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>{{ titleContainer.value }}</h1>
        <input v-model="title">
    </div>
</template>

<script>    
export default {
    data: {
        titleContainer: {}
    }
}
titleContainer.value = "Initial Value"
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to solve your problem with Vue as is since Vue automatically injects reactive getters and setters for all object properties. You could use Object.freeze() on the variable to remove reactivity BUT it would apply across the whole object itself which is not what you want.

I created a fork out of vue called vue-for-babylonians to restrict reactivity and even permit some object properties to be reactive. Check it out [here](https://github.com/cyrilnie/vue-for-babylonians).

With it, you can tell Vue to not make any objects which are stored in vue or vuex from being reactive. You can also tell Vue to make certain subset of object properties reactive. You’ll find performance improves substantially and you enjoy the convenience of storing and passing large objects as you would normally in vue/vuex.