# Performance issue for VueJS component with huge number of read-only (immutable) objects

Tags: performance, vue.js, vue-component

I'm developing a VueJS based JSON viewer (http://treedoc.org) with a tree view. The tree item components are recursively generated based on the JSON doc. When the JSON doc is huge with more than 50k nodes. The rendering becomes extremely slow (could take minutes). I debugged with dev performance tool, I noticed the majority time is spending on the VueJS framework method: *observe()*, *observeArray()*, to build the reactivity dependencies for the attributes in the tree node. However, those tree nodes are read-only, once parser generated those nodes, the content will never be changed. In that case, it doesn't make sense to redefine those properties and observe their changes. How can I optimize those components to avoid VueJS un-necessary build reactivity deps. i.e. Want to make those data in-reactive.

Comment: If you need to skip observation for an object/array in data, use `Object.freeze()` on it. Check out [this comment](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2637#issuecomment-207076744) by Evan himself.

Comment: There is this library [vue-nonreactive](https://github.com/rpkilby/vue-nonreactive) which I think came out of a Vue issue similar to the problem you are facing. I can't find the issue, but recall Evan You suggesting that non-reactive data can be stored outside of the vue component (i.e just a plain JS object).

Comment: I threw an Istanbul coverage file at it (50k lines), and the performance looked ok - a little janky in places but nothing taking minutes. Could you reference you test file?

Comment: Ref [How to set a component non-reactive data in Vue 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45815401/8745435) for a potential solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions,  VUE-nonreactive is a pretty creative solution, but it depends on VUSJS internal data structure, it's a bit risky for future upgrading. I change it to use Object.freeze(), it works pretty well. However, after optimization, it's still low compared to vanilla JS. The sample I used to test is:  https://maps.sensor.community/data/v2/data.24h.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions provided in the comments sections. I summarise those options here:

1. Use **Object.freeze()**: That works for me. It dramatically improves performance. The caveat is only can indicate the **whole** object to be read-only.
2. Use [vue-nonreactive](https://github.com/rpkilby/vue-nonreactive) component, this can specific certain attribute nonreactive. The caveat is it depends on Vue internal data structure by overriding _*ob_*. That will potentially be broken if Vue changes its implementation.
3. Use [vue-static](https://github.com/samuelantonioli/vue-static). This looks nice. However, I haven't tried that as I'm using [Class-Style-Vue-Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Class-Style-Vue-Components).