# How do I loop an non-reactive array in Vue template without putting it in data property or computed property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

I have a static array data like this

```js
const names = ["Amy", "Joseph", "Hank"];
```

I want to loop them in my markup, in React, I can simply do this:

```
import React, { memo } from "react";

// these guys are static values!
const names = ["Amy", "Joseph", "Hank"];

const App = () => (
  <div>
    {names.map(name => ( // render once and no more!
      <span key={name}>{name}</span>
    ))}
  </div>
);

export default memo(App); // won't re-render anymore!
```

But in Vue, the only way I can think of is doing this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span v-for="name in names" :key="name">{{ name }}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const names = ["Amy", "Joseph", "Hank"];

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      names // I have to put these guys in data property, now it becomes reactive, I don't want this. Although this will only render once.
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

I have to put my names in `data()` or `computed` properties, but this will cause them to be reactive, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz because this will cause names to have getters and setters, which makes javascript doing none necessary things.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45815401/9236687

Comment: [This post](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2637#issuecomment-207076744) might also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom option like so

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      //your reactive thins here
    };
  }
  names : ["Amy", "Joseph", "Hank"],
  .......
};
```

And finally in your template you can iterate over it like

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span v-for="name in $option.names">{{ name }}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```