# How to prevent reactivity in form placeholder

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an input field set up as

```js
<input @input="e => machineCIDR = e.target.value" type="text" name="machine" class="form-control form-control-lg" :placeholder="machineCIDR">
```

The problem is, whenever someone fills out the form and then deletes it all, the placeholder is left with the last character that was filled out.

How can I setup `:placeholder="machineCIDR"` so that it shows the *initial* value, and then never gets updated again??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814507/how-to-set-a-component-non-reactive-data-in-vue-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `machineCIDR` is set up already (as a prop or in data), you could create an object for storing all of your initial values:

```js
data() {
  return {
    ...
    initial: {}
  }
}
```

And set up the values in `created`:

```js
created() {
  this.initial['machineCIDR'] = this.machineCIDR;
}
```

Then bind to that instead in the `placeholder`:

```js
:placeholder="initial['machineCIDR']"
```